# How to save the life of Silus Vesuius?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to complete the Pieces of the Past quest without killing Silus, but even if I chose so, two Dremora appear who proceed to kill him immediately. How can I avoid this or protect him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Scripted deaths**

Some deaths in skyrim are scripted. And you cannot avoid the NPC's from being killed. It seems that [Silus](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silus_Vesuius) is not one of those NPC's. So what you want is possible. At least according to the [NPC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silus_Vesuius) and [Quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pieces_of_the_Past#Completing_the_Quest) wiki pages. (It is important to know what you want is possible. In this case, it is possible).

**Normal combat**

Have you tried killing the dremora before they can kill [Silus](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silus_Vesuius)? Try using a [pacify](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pacify_%28spell%29) spell. This means they will not attack for a while, making it easier to draw attention to yourself and save Silus.

I think [dremora](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dremora) are not immune to poisons. So hitting both of them with a paralize poison should freeze them and allow you to kill them without them hitting Silus.

The easiest way to quickly poison them is using a weapon with a high attack speed, such as a knife. Put poison on the blade, quickly hit the first, apply poison, hit the other. Repeat if they stand up.

Using [Alchemy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Paralyze_%28effect%29) you can make your own paralize poisons easily enough. There is also a paralize spell, and a mass paralize spell. But the mass one is pretty high level.

You know the combat is about to happen, so you could cast some summons of your own, and hope they draw away attention from Silus before he gets killed.

You could try sneaking. Start the combat sneaked, and hit one of the dremora for sneak damage. But not sure if that is possible. Do keep us informed about how you managed to protect him.

**[Console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console#Targeted_Commands)**

You can set him to essential, and that way he cannot be killed.

Open the console, and type in "setessential 000240CC 1".

To make him killable again, use "setessential 000240CC 0".

**Change the difficulty**

If you change the difficulty, you will increase the damage you do to the Dremora, that way you could abuse this setting to quickly kill the summons, and then put it back to your normal settings.

*Note*: This only changes the damage the dremora do against the players, and the damage done against them. Silus still gets the same damage from them.

**Just let him die**

Uriel Septim VII wants his revenge! END THE [MYTHIC DAWN](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Mythic_Dawn) BLOODLINE!

Comment: hmm... didn't Uriel already got his revenge by his bastard-turned-dragon-statue son? although Martin didn't killed him, he sure owned Mehrunes right?

Comment: That is what a mythic dawn agent would say! Are you part of the mythic dawn @ken?

Answer (score 5):

If you kill the Dremora before they kill Silus, he will remain friendly to you but you will not be able to use Mehrune's Razor. If you are on PC and are willing to use the console, you can spawn Silus back into the game using:

```
player.placeatme 000240CC 1
```

Comment: Dremora kill Silus almost instantly. How to effectively prevent them from doing so?

Comment: There is no specific way in which you can kill the Dremora. You'd just need to attack them quickly once they appear so they no longer attack Silus, but you instead.

If you want to be even more cheaty, you could go into the console and type `kill` after clicking on them, which will get rid of them.

Comment: Isn't there a banishment spell, perhaps that works. http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Expel_Daedra#Expel_Daedra not sure if the dremora count as summoned.

Comment: @Ids `Only summoned Atronachs and Familiars (but not Flaming Familiars) are affected; Dremora are immune.`, from that link.

Comment: Aha. Didn't read the link that extensive. Well that sucks.

Comment: Do the Demoras have a ranged attack? If not you could use the placeatme command to teleport Silus away form the Demoras giving you more time to kill them.